# Docker container published ports not accessible?

Tags: docker, containers

So here is the situation, I have a container running built with this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2-onbuild
EXPOSE 8888
CMD [ "nohup", "mock-server", "--dir=/usr/src/app", "&" ]
```

I run it with this command:

```
 docker build -t mock_server .
 docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name mocky mock_server
```

I am using it on a mac so boot2docker is going and I hit it from the boot2docker ip on 8888. I tried boot2docker ssh and hitting the container from there. I ran `docker exec -it mocky bash` and `ps aux` shows:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.9 113316 18576 ?        Ss   15:16   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/mock-server --dir=/usr/src/app &
root         5  1.6  0.1  21916  3440 ?        Ss   17:52   0:00 bash
root         9  0.0  0.1  19180  2404 ?        R+   17:53   0:00 ps aux
```

When I cURL it:

```
curl -I -XGET localhost:8888/__manage
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 183108
Set-Cookie: flash_msg_success=; expires=Thu, 04 Sep 2014 17:54:58 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: flash_msg_error=; expires=Thu, 04 Sep 2014 17:54:58 GMT; Path=/
Server: TornadoServer/4.2.1
Etag: "efdb5b362491b8e4b8347b97ccafeca02db8d27d"
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 17:54:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So I the app is running inside the container but I can't get anything from outside it.  What can be done here?

Comment: Aside: no need for `nohup` in your Dockerfile CMD line.

Comment: @PeterLyons if I don't do something like `nohup` the server mock-server doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Ah maybe it exits if stdin is not a tty or something, which it probably shouldn't do. But just FYI for most proper network servers, `nohup` is not required and should not be used within a docker `CMD` line.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First guess is the python program is explicitly binding to the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1` which disallows any remote connections. Check the docs for that python mock tornado server for something like `--bind=0.0.0.0` and adjust accordingly.

You can confirm if this is the case by doing a docker exec and in the container running `netstat -ntlp | grep 8888` and seeing which IP is bound. If it's `127.0.0.1`, that confirms that is indeed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out and came to see that you gave a similar answer.  I did not realize that you couldn't serve within the container on the localhost or loopback address.  Specifically for this problem I changed the Dockerfile CMD to: `CMD [ "nohup", "mock-server", "--dir=/usr/src/app", "--address=0.0.0.0", "&" ]`

Comment: Thank you Peter, @peter-lyons finally followed this i had the same issue while running a sinatra application with docker .. upvoted :-)

Answer (score 3):

Docker runs on top of an OS and docker machine has its own ip address. One possible reason why the port is not accessible is that you are using localhost which is trying to hit 127.0.0.1: but your docker machine might be running another ip address hence by replacing the ip address your curl should work.

$ docker-machine ip default

This should give you docker machine's ip address replace it with localhost.

Comment: This was it for me! If you're running on OSX you have to use docker-machine and so you're likely seeing this. Whatever client you're running you'll have to specify the hostname along with the port. For example postgres would be `psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5433 -U postgres` (replace hostname with whatever `docker-machine ip default` returns