# Spring Boot: Connection timed out when trying to call a service from a service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, netflix-eureka

I have 2 microservices + an Eureka Server in which they are registerd.
I made really everything I could think of, yet when I try to call the login service from the manager service, I always get "Connection timed out".

```
POST http://localhost:9903/login

{
    "username":"adm4",
    "password":"adm4adm4"
}
```

I have tried to work with Spring RestTemplate and WebClient and also Apache HttpClient.
All the times, the flow reaches the post method, and I get the same result.
I guess it must be some configuration issue.

I am working on localhost with all modules.

It really drives me crzay!

Please advise. I appreciate it.

The relevant info is as follows. Please tell me if you need more info.

First of all you can see that the services are registered and up:

[image]

Next the code:

Manager (calling) Service:
(I left inside all my previous attempts commented)

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public void login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) throws Exception {

        String url = getBaseUrl("bbsim-login-service") + "/api/auth/signin";

/*         CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getBaseUrl("bbsim-login-service") + "/api/auth/signin");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", loginRequest.getUsername()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginRequest.getPassword()));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
 */
/*         HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        // Connect timeout: time is in milliseconds
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        // Read timeout: time is in milliseconds
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

        HttpEntity<LoginRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(loginRequest);
        JwtResponse res = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, JwtResponse.class);
        System.out.println(res); 
*/

        localApiClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .body(Mono.just(loginRequest), LoginRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JwtResponse.class)
                .block();

    }

    private String getBaseUrl(String serviceName) {

        Application application = eurekaClient.getApplication(serviceName);
        InstanceInfo instanceInfo = application.getInstances().get(0);
        String hostname = instanceInfo.getHostName();
        int port = instanceInfo.getPort();
        return "http://" + hostname + ":" + port;
    }
```

application.yml:

```
server.port: 9903

spring:
    application.name: bbsim-manager-service

eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8088/eureka}
            registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
            # register-with-eureka: true
            # fetch-registry: true
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

If I understand well, the request does not reach the login service at all.

---

Login (called) service:

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();      
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                userDetails.getId(), 
                userDetails.getUsername(), 
                userDetails.getEmail(), 
            roles));
}
```

application.yml file:

```
server.port: 9902

spring:
    application:
        name: bbsim-login-service

eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:8088/eureka/
            registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
            instance:
                leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

I addition, I tried the following - giving me the same results:

```
curl -d "@data.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9903/login
```

where data.json has the body contents.

Comment: can you reach your login service using `curl` ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi Thank you Abdeighani. 
I tried curl -d "@data.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9903/login and recieved :
AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: host.docker.internal/192.168.1.177:9902","path":"/login"

Comment: It has nothing to do with `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`. So have you exposed port 9902 when you've started your docker container ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi I must say that this is my first spring project. Although I see that docker is involved here (host.docker.internal), directly I didn't do anything related to docker. Isn't the port definition in the yaml file the answer for your question? If not - what should I do?

Comment: this seems to a problem connecting to an application running inside docker. I think you might need port forwarding on docker https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_managing_ports.htm
https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports

Comment: @SunilKumar I am working on Windows, and following the tutorial, I didn't find any docker containers on the dashboard although the services were up and running. I am checking this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404011/docker-container-published-ports-not-accessible...

Comment: Please, can you indicate the value returned from the method `getBaseUrl(String serviceName)` in the manager service?

Comment: @jccampanero When executing curl -d "{"""username""":"""adm4""","""password""":"""adm4adm4"""}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9903/login, getBaseURL (which is I actually use as the full WebClient uri ) gives me http://host.docker.internal:9902/api/auth/signin

Comment: Thank you very much @dushkin. I will post an answer with some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be a complete answer but I hope it helps you with your issue.

I think your problem could be related with a mix of the different IP address of your machine.

First, I think Eureka is exposing your services like `host.docker.internal`, as indicated, the logical name that references the host machine through the different docker containers, for the reason explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57319678/spring-boot-cloud-eurka-windows-10-eurkea-returns-host-docker-internal-for-clien).

Basically, it seems that the docker software is updating your `hosts` file with entries for `host.docker.internal` and `gateway.docker.internal` and Eureka probably is taking that alias as the one for the machine IP that is being advertised. Please, see the accepted answer in the aforementioned question.

When you run Spring Boot normally the underlying server (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow) will listen for connections in the `0.0.0.0` address, i.e., in all the network interfaces available, including `localhost`. This is what troubles me, because as indicated, the service should be accessible through all the IPs in the machine.

In any way, I think you can try several things to solve your issue.

Probably the best approach to solve the problem will be to configure the `hostname` of your Eureka server and/or your Eureka clients to a common one.

For example, you can configure your server and clients to be exposed as `localhost`.

For that purpose, you need to include the following configuration property in their respective config files:

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

Comment: Thank you @jccampanero for your time. Can you please edit your answer by specifying if each step is to be added to the previous or should be performed based on the preliminary state which is with the additions of Docker desktop to the hosts file? I have my assumptions (which currently didn't work out), but I'd like to have your distinct instructions.

Comment: Hi @dushkin. Yes, of course. In any way, the idea is that every change must be applied separately, you must not mix the different solutions. Sorry, I will try to clarify the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please, try each solution independently. I would start with solution 3. If it does not work, solution 4. Did you try them? For your comment, they are not working? Please, the first step in any case should be to analyze your `hosts` file and see how it looks like, confirm that the docker related entries are included.

Comment: So my initial state of hosts should be with the automatic configued host.docker.internal entry, right? And except for the first option, I should leave it in the hosts file. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes @dushkin, leave as is.  As you can see in the SO question indicated in the answer, it seems something maintained by the docker software and probably although you remove these entries from your hosts file there will be there after rebooting your system. Please, leave as is, and try every solution independently

Comment: Solution 4 is the winner!!! I'll be happy to accept the answer. Would you like to modify the answer first? Also, is this the best soultion or only a workaorund which hides any problem in my code?

Comment: Great @dushkin!! I am happy to see that the answer was helpful. I modified the answer. No, as I told in the answer, there could be other options, but this option is certainly a good solution. I think your code is right, and the problem is motivated by the docker networking issue. The only possible drawback of the solution, please, keep that it mind, is that you will need to adapt the hostname to one appropriate when you deploy the application to other environment. In any case, it should not be a problem because you can include different spring profiles and/or use environment variables for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226822/discussion-between-dushkin-and-jccampanero).

Comment: @dushkin I am unable to chat now, but I will be glad to chat later if you need to. Please, can we meet in about three hours? Please, sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: There's no hurry. It was a "futurewise" question. I am not going to deal with that before the weekend. I'll be happy to contact you whenever required. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @dushkin. Please, sorry, I was unable to come before. You are welcome. Yes, please, do not hesitate to contact me when you consider appropriate, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Docker. You are trying to connect to localhost but other services are running in other container hence localhost won’t work. Would you please try `0.0.0.0` or `host.docker.internal` in your YAML file and see if that will work.

In other words you will need to edit following.

```
server.port: 9903
    
    spring:
        application.name: bbsim-manager-service
    
    eureka:
        client:
            serviceUrl:
                defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://host.docker.internal:8088/eureka}
                registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
                # register-with-eureka: true
                # fetch-registry: true
        instance:
            leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

or change `EUREKA_URI` env variable to reflect that. Also in your service YAML

```
    server.port: 9902
    
    spring:
        application:
            name: bbsim-login-service
    
    eureka:
        client:
            serviceUrl:
                defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://host.docker.internal:8088/eureka/}
                registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
                instance:
                    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

Comment: In yaml or hosts file?

Comment: In yaml file since all your services running in container. Did you post host file too?

Comment: Thank you for your time. 1. What do you mean in "Did you post host file too"? 2. On which projects yaml? The eureka server, the services, all of them? And anyway, what is the correct way to set it on yaml file? host.docker.internal is not "a known property" on the yamls.

Comment: I made the changes of replacing the localhost with host.docker.internal for the defaultZone values on both services.
The calling service threw "task supervisor timed out" while loading and didn't load.
The called service threw I/O error on GET request for "http://host.docker.internal:8088/eureka/apps/": Connection timed out. I didn't understand if and where should I also replace EUREKA_URI?

Comment: Looks like you are not exposing your port properly using Docker. Can you post your Dockerfile.

Comment: I didn't write any docker file. All I did is created 3 spring-boot applications, one is annotated as a Eureka Server using EnableEurekaServer annotaion and the two others are clients of this server, annotated with EnableDiscoveryClient annotaion. I didn't have any direct docker work here, excpt that the services are loaded, apparently, inside a docker...

Comment: Ok what do you get when you do docker ps

Comment: an empty list... remember that noth services failed to be loaded after the change I made. I'll try also with the original mapping

Comment: If you are getting nothing for docker ps while running all your services then that means none of your services are running. You will need to run the service containers first. Furthermore since you are just using localhost as test there is no need to use docker if you don’t want to.

Comment: please see my last comment

Comment: Oh ok sorry I missed that part. I would recommend to not use docker for now and change everything to localhost. Once it’s working then you can move things to docker then. Also you said you don’t have Dockerfile then how you were running things before?

Comment: Ok, I restored the default zones to use localhost, the services are up (I can see them also in the Eureka Server dahsboard as (for example) host.docker.internal:bbsim-login-service:9902 which is linked to http://host.docker.internal:9902/actuator/info. But docker ps list is still empty. Is there a relation anyhow between these services to my Docker Desktop on Windows? The services were up and running even before I launched the Docker Desktop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226669/discussion-between-dushkin-and-nicholasnet).